# How to configure a network printer using command prompt under Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, network-printer

I have a network printer that is properly shared under Windows 7 on network with Windows 7 computers, but when configuring it in command prompt with:

```
net use lpt1: \\zzzz\laser /persistent:yes
```

then it requires a user name and password. How can I configure the printer so that this is no longer required?

Comment: @Feroz, next time please take some more time to properly phrase your question. Not everyone is willing to decypher your question, so your less likely to receive an answer. Good luck on your next question!

Answer (score 2):

To add a network printer through the command line:

```
rundll32 printui.dll,PrintUIEntry /ga /c\\computername /n\\servername\printersharename
```

This adds the shared printer on the server for all users of the computer "computername". Note that `PrintUIEntry` is case-sensitive, which can be a bit of a pitfall.

Refer to [http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624057(v=ws.10).aspx](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee624057%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) for more details.